# openpyxl and iteration + alter specific cells question/seeking resource

Tags: python, python-3.x, iteration, openpyxl

Very new to python here. Need some help with using openpyxl, please! This is for a personal project on my self-learning journey. I'm looking for a resource to show me how to do the following thing in pip3 openpyxl:

I have a class that has a variable which acts as a unique identifier. This is the first column in my excel workbook. What I want to do:

I want to add new IDs to the spreadsheet. This means, first, I need to iterate over only the first column and make sure the new unique identifier isn't already present. I believe the following code does this iteration successfully:

```
for row in sheet.iter_rows('A{}:A{}'.format(sheet.min_row,sheet.max_row)):
```

Then, if the unique identifier is not present, meaning the ID is not already contained within the dataset, I want to add that ID and its associated class values to the dataset in a new row. I think the following line does that, inserting a new row right under the header row:

```
sheet.insert_rows(idx=2)
```

Then I write code below that to fill the rest of the cells in that row with the appropriate values.

Else if the unique identifier is already present, I want to use *some* of the data from the row containing that identifier and the associated class values, do some recalculations on *those* cells, and then update *some* of the *other* values/cells in the row, overwriting the old values. This is what I specifically need help with.

Based on something I saw elsewhere, this is my idea, putting everything together:

```
for row in sheet.iter_rows('A{}:A{}'.format(sheet.min_row,sheet.max_row)):
    if fin.fin != row:
```

fin is the unique ID which is the name given to each case and also an attribute stored in the class. I'm also wondering if != row will work here or if I need to index like row[0] or if row.value should be used?

```
        sheet.insert_rows(idx=2)
        sheet["A2"] = fin.fin     #setting cell A2 = unique id attribute of my class instance
        sheet["B2"] = fin.kgs     #setting cell B2 = kgs attribute of my class instance
        sheet["F2"] = fin.kgs_to_lbs() #setting cell F2 to module output converting kgs to lbs
    else:
        sheet['B{}'.format(row)] = fin.kgs.format(row) #if the id is not unique, change value in column B of that row
        sheet['F{}'].format(row) = fin.kgs_to_lbs.format(row) #if the id is not unique, change value in column F of that row
```

Hopefully that's clear. Let me know if anything isn't. I'm looking either for some sample code or a reference to a resource that would be helpful, please!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some issues with your code there. Ath the momnet your code is iterating over the cells in column A and checking if a cell object is equal to your attribute `fin.fin` which I assume is either a string or an integer (?). Since they arent it will **always** be `FALSE` thus creating a new row above row `2`.

So, the question you are trying to answer is in actuallity - *Does `fin.fin` already exists in column `A`?*. For that you can just take the list of values in column A and check if `fin.fin` is in it, we will use a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) to build it:

```
known_identifiers = [cell.value for cell in ws['A']]  # Creating a list of all known identifiers from column A

if fin.fin is not in known_identifiers:
    # Special identifier is not in the Excel file add it and data

    sheet.insert_rows(idx=2)

    sheet["A2"] = fin.fin  # setting cell A2 = unique id attribute of my class instance
    sheet["B2"] = fin.kgs  # setting cell B2 = kgs attribute of my class instance
    sheet["F2"] = fin.kgs_to_lbs()  #setting cell F2 to module output converting kgs to lbs


else:
    # Identifier found, Change data in specific columns.

   row = known_identifiers.index(fin.fin)+1  # Row is the same as the item list index+1 (As lists start from 0 and rows from 1)         
   sheet[f"B{row}"] = fin.kgs.format(row)  # Not sure why you need `format` here but it's your class
   sheet[f"F{row}"] = fin.kgs_to_lbs.format(row) # Same
```

Do notice that `int(identifier) != str(identifier)` so be sure you're checking variables of the same type, if needed convert one or the other. Also, I have used **f-strings** in my code as I think it generates a nicer cleaner code, you can read about those - [Here](https://realpython.com/python-f-strings/).

Comment: Ah, yes! So the original problem is there are going to be many instances where the fin.fin attribute is not equal to cell and will insert a row, even if fin.fin exists somewhere in the column A. It's so obvious in hindsight. This makes sense. Thank you!
I'm not sure why I need .format either. I pulled it from other code I found, but I don't really understand it (hence this post). It seems like I don't need the .format command at all, right? sheet[f"B{row}"] already selects the necessary cell, right?

Comment: @Michael, I was talking about the `format` in `fin.kgs.format(row)` which is part of the class you wrote, I can't tell you how to call it as I don't know the actual code. The `f"B{row}"` is just another way to format, it is the same as `"B{}".format(row)`.

Comment: Ah, ok. So I think I was being redundant then. I will learn more about the .format command. I was just trying to follow code I saw elsewhere for applying a formula to a cell and changing a cell. That's the part I was totally unfamiliar with. Thanks so much for your help. Means a lot.